# Adding an ID to an image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've tried searching other questions on this site, and I've yet to find one that is encountering the same problem as me:

I'm trying to add an ID to an image every time the image is clicked so I may apply a certain styling to the image. This is the code I've used to try and accomplish this:

```
    <div class="imgThumbnail">

        <img src="" />
        <img src="" />

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            //hover over thumbnail effect
           $('.imgThumbnail img').hover(
               function() {
                $(this).css({"height":"18vh","width":"18vh"})},

               function() {
                $(this).css({"height":"17vh","width":"17vh"});    
           }); 

            //selected effect
           $('.imgThumbnail img').click(function(){
              (this).attr("id","selected");
           });

        });
```

Despite all of my trouble shooting efforts, I've yet to find the problem in my code. I've changed the .attr() in the click function to .clear() to test if I was targeting the correct images, and if the click was being registered. This cleared the image I clicked on, as expected. Then I placed $(this).attr("id", "selected") to my hover function, and it added the styling from my "selected" id as expected.

So why won't the id properly add to the image when I use a click function?

I am new to jQuery. I am also still new to navigating this site, so if you can find the answer else where, I would appreciate redirection. Thanks!

Comment: I can't really understand your problem. But do you just want to add a class to the image you clicked on?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. I want to add an id when an image is clicked on, and the code I've used is not working.

Comment: It's a bad practice to have multiple elements with the same ID. You should use class instead

Comment: My code isn't complete. The ID will be removed when another element is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is 99% complete. You just forgot the *$*  before the final *this*.

This is what your javascript should look like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //hover over thumbnail effect
       $('.imgThumbnail img').hover(
           function() {
            $(this).css({"height":"18vh","width":"18vh"})},

           function() {
            $(this).css({"height":"17vh","width":"17vh"});    
       }); 

        //selected effect
       $('.imgThumbnail img').click(function(){
          $(this).attr("id","selected");
       });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks… rookie mistake. It works now. I'm a little embarrassed.

Comment: @ADB It's OK, we're humans... :) I would advice you however to use a class if you are going to style the image with css. The way you do this in jQuery is with `.addClass("class")`.

Comment: Yea, I already switched after you showed me my mistake. I realized I switched to adding an ID instead of a class while trouble shooting. Thanks again. In accordance with this sites protocols, should I delete my question since it is not really helpful to the community?

Comment: I'm new to this site, too. I don't know actually.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle a class on click make a .click() function and then use toggleClass
This will toggle the class everytime you click the selected class. use classes not id's for this kinda stuff

```
$('.imgThumbnail img').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('yourClass');
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h6Lpe8c/1/)

Comment: I'm not trying to toggle a class. Thanks though.

Comment: I probably used a class hours ago, and switched to an ID while trouble shooting. I still do not want a toggle affect. I want the style to apply only to the photo I click on. But I'll figure that out on my own, it shouldn't be too difficult.